# What is the origin of the counting prefixes: uni-, bi-/di-, tri-, quad-, etc.?

Tags: etymology, numbers, latin

Many English words use the prefixes uni-, bi-/di-, tri-, quad- and so on to mean one, two, three, and four. For example:

> A unicycle has one wheel, a bicycle two, and a tricycle three.

I presume these prefixes are either of Greek or Latin origin, but from what little I know of these two languages, neither uses these prefixes as their numbers. That is, in Greek you wouldn't start counting by saying, *Uni, di, tri, quad, ...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, they are from Latin and Greek, we have simply inherited terms from both. There is a good [reference for Latin and Greek roots over at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English):

**Uni** meaning *one*:

> un-, uni- one
>
> - **language of origin**: Latin
> - **etymology**: unus, unius
> - **examples**: unary, union

**Bi/Di** meaning two:

> bi-   two
>
> - **language of origin**: Latin
> - **etymology**: bis, "twice"; bini, "in twos"
> - **examples**: *binoculars*, *bigamy*, *biscotti*
>
> di-   two
>
> - **language of origin**: Greek
> - **etymology**: δι,
> - **examples**: *dicot*, *dipole*

**Quadr** meaning *four*:

> quadr-    four
>
> - **language of origin**: Latin
> - **etymology**: quattuor
> - **examples**: quadrangle, quadrillion

And so on; there are a lot of these and I'm no expert but believe that, although some of the roots from Latin and Greek essentially mean the same, there are some [constraints on which ones to use in certain circumstances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Terminology) (see also: [hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection).) But don't quote me on that, though, I'll try and look a little information up.

Comment: Here's a list of the [PIE numerals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/PIE-numerals.jpg), with cognates in major languages (including Latin and Greek).

Comment: biscotti are two cotti? Whasas cotto?

Comment: those PIE charts always drive me crazy because often the root and the target seem so different that it makes me wonder.

Comment: @Lambie *cotto* is the Italian past participle of *cuocere* so *biscotti* is "cooked twice".  Biscuits are similar, through French

Comment: The WP link to `Octoups#Terminology` no longer works. Is this a reference to the following? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Etymology_and_pluralisation

Answer (score 11):

They do come from both Latin and Greek as follows (along with the rest, up to ten):

**uni** comes from the Latin *unus*, meaning "one"
**di** comes from the Latin *dis*, meaning "twice" (originally from the Greek prefix *di-* meaning "two"
**tri** comes from the Latin *tres* (Greek *treis*), meaning *three*
**quadra** comes from the Latin *quattuor*, meaning "four"
**quinta/penta** comes from the Latin *quintus*, meaning "fifth" and the Greek *pente*, meaning "five"
**hexa** comes from the Greek *hex*, meaning "six" (Latin is *sex*)
**septa** comes from the Latin *septem*, meaning "seven" (Greek is *hepta*) m
**octa/o** comes from the Latin *octo* (Greek *okto*), meaning "eight"
**nona** comes from the Latin *nonus*, meaning "ninth"
**deca/deci** comes from the Greek *deka*, meaning "ten" and from the Latin *decimus*, meaning "tenth"

Comment: We also use **penta-** from Greek _pente_, meaning "five", and **deci-** from the Latin ordinal _decimus_ (presumably by way of Greek). There are also (at least) two specialized words using Greek numbers rather than Latin: "tesseract", from _tessera_, meaning "four", and "enneagram" from _ennea_, "nine".

Comment: It's "quattuor", not "quattour".

Answer (score 1):

It's true that in Latin there are words like "bis" ("twice") or "bini" ("in pairs") but the actual word "bi" is probably not a Latin word. "Two" in Latin is "duo". Taken separately, "bi" doesn't mean anything in Latin and is perhaps a borrowing from the early Basque language which isn't even Indo-European. "Bi", even in modern Basque, means "two". ("one, two, three, four, five" in Basque: "bat, bi, huru, lau, bost").

Comment: "bi-" is not a borrowing from Basque. It's a combining form of "duo" that developed from earlier dwi- by a sound change dw- > b- (also seen in words like "bellum" < dwellum (or "duellum").

Comment: "Biscotti" meant originally "twice cooked", "cotti" being Italian for "cooked".  Cf. "biscuit" from French, "-cuit" being "cooked" in French, and "zwieback", "twice-baked", from German "Zwei", i.e., two, and "back", from "backen", to bake  or fry.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the prefixes came from Latin (and Greek), and entered the widespread lexicon from the formal, scientific origins (primarily medicine and biology), where it was an established practice to use formal Latin in the naming and description of observed phenomena.