# Prefix di- and bi-

Tags: prefixes

I was wondering if there are differences between the cases of using di- and the cases of using bi-?

For example,

- why carbon dioxide instead of carbon bioxide?
- Why binoculars instead of dinoculars?
- Why bisexual instead of disexual?
- Why bilateral instead of dilateral?

Comment: Almost 2k points and you're still saying "thanks" in a post?

Comment: Don't say "thanks" in a post. It's spam.

Comment: Related to "[what is the origin of the counting prefixes uni- bi- di- tri- quad etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/what-is-the-origin-of-the-counting-prefixes-uni-bi-di-tri-quad-etc)"

Comment: @Tim [why people remove thanks from posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @MattЭллен: What if I don't buy that?

Comment: Then prepare to be disappointed, because many people abide by it. I'm afraid I can't offer you solace on this one. Personally I'm with [The Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2960/147791) on this issue.

Comment: Binosaurs? Dile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Bi-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bi-) comes from Latin, [Di-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/di-) from Greek. Which prefix is used would usually depend on the origin of the root of the word.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I have to learn history of each such word! Possibly any rule saying that which is used more often in what category? For example, in chemistry, di-; in social science and physics, bi-?

Comment: Precisely. *Dioxide* is a Greek word, whereas *binoculars* and *bisexual* are of Latin origin. +1.

Comment: You could learn the history ... or you could just accept whatever you find in the dictionary. While it is sometimes useful to know the origins of a word, 95% of the time you can just use it without having to know that it came from Latin via French or that it was coined by Hiram Slocum in 1892 or whatever.

Comment: Plenty of Latin words have the prefix *di-* or *dis-* thought they often lose the sense of 2 by the time they arrive in English: compare bisection and dissection.

Comment: @Henry: In mathematics, is bi- more often than di-? I cannot think of some examples with di-.

Comment: @Tim: from Latin there are examples such as *difference* and *discrete* and from Greek *diagonal*

Comment: @Henry: Thanks! But do they all mean two things? Seems like there is no word with di- and meaning two things.

Comment: @Henry: No. The Latin words in "di-" have a meaning of "apart", or "separate" (eg "differ", "diverge"), not originally "two". "Diagonal" has yet another origin, Greek "across".

Comment: @Tim: Greek roots are perhaps less common than Latin ones in many branches of mathematics, but not in Geometry, where you can find "dihedral angle" (the angle between two faces of a solid).

Comment: @Colin: I suspect that all of the "apart" meanings stem from "two". Wiktionary takes [*di-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dis-#Latin) back to a reconstructed proto-IndoEuropean dwis, and [*bi-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bis#Latin) back to dwóh₁, both related to the English *twice* and *two*.

Comment: @Henry. Apparently so. I'm surprised, because "bis" is the normal Latin reflex of "dwis" (cf "bellum" for "duellum"), but the OED agrees that "dis-" is from that same root.

Comment: @Tim: diagonal, diagram, diophantine equation, diffeomorphism, ...