# “bigamy” and “digamy”

Tags: prefixes

- ***bi‑***  from Latin with the meaning of *two*.
- ***di‑***  is the Greek counterpart of *bi‑*, with the same meaning of *two*.

Are *bigamy* and *digamy* words with the same meaning. If not, why?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57600/prefix-di-and-bi?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Digamy* was once used synonymously with *bigamy*, but now, if it is used at all, it means a second marriage, or re-marriage after the death of the first spouse.

Answer (score 4):

*[Bigamy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bigamy#Noun)*  ordinarily refers to “The state of having two (legal or illegal) spouses simultaneously”, but in an ecclesiastical context may mean “a second marriage”.

*[Digamy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digamy#Noun)* also refers to second marriages, but “as after the death or divorce of a spouse”.   The term *[deuterogamy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deuterogamy)* is slightly more specific: “A second marriage, after the death of the first husband [or] wife; in distinction from bigamy, as defined in the old canon law”.